Excel FILTER / XLOOPUP / VLOOKUP / TEXTJOIN
I'm lost and not finding the correct formula.
I have a sheet in Excel that looks like this:
[CODE] - [CATEGORY] - [SUBCATEGORY] - [DETAILS]
And I have a 2nd Excel sheet with a column [DESCRIPTION].
I want now to add the category/subcategory/details from sheet 1, based on the description column in my table from sheet 2. The [CODE] from sheet 1 can be found as part of multiple descriptions from the description column in sheet 2.
Example:
Sheet 1:



CODE
CATEGORY
SUBCATEGORY
DETAILS




ABC
CAT 1
SUBCAT 1.1
DETAILS1


DEF
CAT 2
SUBCAT 2.1
DETAILS2



In sheet 2 in [DESCRIPTIONS]:
"ABC DEF"
So this description field matches up with 2 codes: so the codes from both lines can be found in the description (wildmatch search).
Now I want to enrich in sheet 2, after the description field, I want to have a new column called "Categories" that will contain "ABC | DEF" so it should concatenate ALL the matches that it finds.
How can I achieve this?
I tried a lot with the formulas as mentioned in the title but I cannot get it to work...
Example what I want to achieve:



DATE
DESCRIPTIONS
AMOUNT
Category
Sub-Category
Details




1/1/2024
From checking account with description ZEB
-50
Expense
Shopping
Detail 1


1/2/2024
Salary income Formula 1 from Ecclestone
10000
Income
Formula 1 | Ecclestone
Detail 2 | Detail 4


1/3/2024
JOBBONUS

Income
Salary
Detail 5




You could try using the following formula:
Updated as per new edit in OP:


=TEXTJOIN(" | ",1,UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(
 FILTER(Table1,1-ISERR(SEARCH(" "&Table1[Code]&" "," "&Sheet2!$B2&" "))),
 XMATCH(D$1,Table1[#Headers]))))


Or,
 =TEXTJOIN(" | ",1,UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(
 FILTER(Table1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&Table1[Code]&" "," "&Sheet2!$B2&" "))),
 XMATCH(D$1,Table1[#Headers]))))


Note that I have structured the sheet one source data into Structured References aka Tables so that the formula resizes automatically, when there is addition of more data in the actual source.

To make it more readable and usable to understand, so that if you face any issues, can debug and evaluate easily to find therefore you may write in this way as well:
=LET(
     _Find_Text, " "&Table1[Code]&" ",
     _Within_Text, " "&Sheet2!$B2&" ",
     _Include, 1-ISERROR(SEARCH(_Find_Text, _Within_Text)),
     _Array, FILTER(Table1, _Include, ""),
     _Column_Index, XMATCH(D$1, Table1[#Headers]),
     _Unique, UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(_Array, _Column_Index)),
     _Output, TEXTJOIN(" | ",1,_Unique),
     _Output)



This only works assuming you split the text by spaces but I would need a wildmatch search. How can I achieve this?
Sometimes the text I need to search is like a few words with spaces in between them breaking this solution. So the textsplit part needs to be a wildmatch in fact.

@Gennaro then do it in this way: =TEXTJOIN("|",1,FILTER(Table1[CODE],ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table1[CODE],Sheet2!A2))))
This works, but it returns me the Code, not the Category and/or Sub Category

I have edited my question with a screenshot with what I want to achieve.

Sorry I posted an incorrect picture, the one I have there now is what I want

This works but now I face another issue (see updated screenshot)

@Everyone , I managed to get it working, I made a mistake in my last post, but I really appreciate all of your help, it helped me immensely.

@Gennaro I have updated per your new requirements, and if this solves please ensure to click on the checkmark beside the answer to close the thread!




Steps
Variables/Functions




Define variables for data ranges
codes_and_categories, descriptions, codes, details


Define function to get details for a row in descriptions
get_details


For each value descr, get the details by doing a wildcard match against codes (COUNTIF can do wildcard match)
details_, FILTER(details, COUNTIF(descr, "*" & codes & "*"), "")


For each column (categories etc.), we want to combine the results in  as text delimited by |, building the row with HSTACK
HSTACK(acc, TEXTJOIN(" | ", , INDEX(details_, , col_)))


Accumlated row of results in the final result
VSTACK(acc, combined_details_for_row)


In the accumulated results, drop the initial rows that we do not need
result, DROP(REDUCE("", descriptions, get_details), 1),


Replace not found (#N/A) results from FILTER
IFNA(result, "")



=LET(
    codes_and_categories, A2:INDEX(Sheet1!D2:D500, COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A500)),
    descriptions, H2:INDEX(H2:H500, COUNTA(H2:H500) + 1),
    codes, INDEX(codes_and_categories, , 1),
    details, DROP(codes_and_categories, , 1),
    get_details, LAMBDA(acc, descr,
        LET(
            details_, FILTER(details, COUNTIF(descr, "*" & codes & "*"), ""),
            combined_details_for_row, DROP(
                REDUCE(
                    "",
                    SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(details_)),
                    LAMBDA(acc, col_,
                        HSTACK(acc, TEXTJOIN(" | ", , INDEX(details_, , col_)))
                    )
                ),
                ,
                1
            ),
            VSTACK(acc, combined_details_for_row)
        )
    ),
    result, DROP(REDUCE("", descriptions, get_details), 1),
    IFNA(result, "")
)


